# Binding value from resource.resx to Header of  DataGridTemplateColumn

Tags: xaml, data-binding, silverlight-4.0, resources

I get an error:

```
Cannot find a Resource with the Name/Key ResourceString [Line: 94 Position: 104]
```

in my xaml:

```
<data:DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="PriorityColumn" CanUserSort="True" Header="{Binding columnHeader_PriorityColumn, Source={StaticResource ResourceString}}">
```

But I can't bind element from resource to texblock

After some investigation I figured out that it's because I can only user Resource.resx to controls listed at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd882554(v=vs.95).aspx

So if I have right, is there other way to bind value do header of DataGridTemplateColumn?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you need to bind value from resource file. If that is the question then  you should wrap Resource with `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Try to do something like this:

```
public class ResourceWrapper : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
        private static readonly Resource resourceHelper = new Resource();

        public Resource ResourceHelper
        {
            get { return resourceHelper; }
            set { NotifyChange("ResourceHelper"); }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void NotifyChange(String name)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
```

In xaml do something like:

```
...
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <helper:ResourceWrapper x:Name="ResourceString" />
    </UserControl.Resources>
...
```

and finally

```
<data:DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="PriorityColumn" CanUserSort="True" Header="{Binding ResourceHelper.NeededString, Source={StaticResource ResourceString}}">
```

Hope it'll help you.